# Not able to see the GRUB after updating with rerular updates...in14.04

Tags: 14.04, process, boot

After updating with regular updates of packages of 14.04 ..
my system started to boot directly to windows ....
how i would be able to get it back

Answer (score 0):

Use Boot-repair tool of Ubuntu:
1: Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu"
2: Connect Internet
3: Open Terminal ctrl + alt + t
4: Execute following command

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

5: Launch boot-repair and select Recommended-repair
6: Once finished reboot  check if you recovered access to your OSs.

OR You can use Windows EasyBCD tool to repair you boot
   here's the link http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

Run the Program and select
   Add New Entry -> linux tab ->
       a) Select Grub2
       b) Select A name for your ubuntu distribution
       c) Select the drive where your ubuntu 14.04 is installed
       d) Once done save and reboot check if you recovered access to your OSs.